# Ways of applying the phrase: "in/after the fashion (of)"

Tags: phrase-usage

A situation relates to a not well-off person trying to live large anyway while being on vacation.
Is it possible to exploit the phrase "in/after the fashion" as it stands in the following patterns?

1. "I've decided to spend my vacation after the fashion of the rich".
2. "...in/after a rich man fashion".
3. "...in/after a rich man's fashion".
4. "...in/after a rich men fashion".
5. "...in/after a rich men's fashion"
6. "...in/after a rich fashion"

or

7. "...in/after a mendicant fashion".
8. "...in/after the fashion of the mendicant.
9. "...in/after the fashion of mendicants.

Which of them can be discerned rightly and are relevant and correct?

Comment: What do you mean by "discerned rightly"?

Comment: I don't find *any* of the examples particularly natural. I'd just say ***like a rich man, like a beggar***.

Comment: **after a fashion** means **sort of**. In does not  mean: in the manner of or like a.  Your sentences are not idiomatic, if you want the truth...

Comment: Userr2684291, I wanted to say "understood in the right way".

Answer (score 1):

Your examples 2 and 4 are incorrect, because a possessive from is needed in this construction, as in numbers 3 and 5.  I think 3 is better than 5, as you are one person and should be compared with an individual "man" not with "men". In any case one should not say "a rich men's fashion" because the article "a" implies a singular form, and this is plural. Instead, "the fashion of rich men" or "the fashion of the rich" could work here.

Example number 6 "in a rich fashion" is grammatical, but carries a different meaning. "Rich" here would mean "full" or 'vivid" not "wealthy" or "opulent", and this would be a rather unusual form.

Numbers 7 and 9 are grammatical, but I suspect a confusion of meaning. The word  ["mendicant"](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/mendicant) is an elaborate word for a beggar, now somewhat old-fashioned, and I doubt that this is what is intended.

This whole use of "fashion" is a bit unusual, although not unprecedented or wrong, but I think i would try to find a different way to express this idea, such as:

> I've decided to spend my vacation as a rich man might.

Comment: Thank you very much for the helpful advice. The reason why I resorted to the word "fashion" was my intention to bring the strain of my statement's implication round to that of humour.